Buffer Overflow strange behavior for RIP
I run test i gdb to exploit an buffer overflow, when testing with:
(gdb) r $(python3 -c 'print(b"\x41"*152+"\x42"*6 )')
(gdb) i r
...
rbp            0x4141414141414141       0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffffffe420   0x7fffffffe420
rip            0x424242424242   0x424242424242
...

I got 0x424242424242 that is 'BBBBBB', perfect!
But when testing with the adress: 0x7fffffffe370
r $(python3 -c 'print(b"\x41"*152+b"\x70\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f")')
(gdb) i r
...
rbp            0x4141414141414141       0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffffffe3f8   0x7fffffffe3f8
rip            0x400694 0x400694 <main+171>
...

I got 0x400694 0x400694 <main+171>, I should have 0x7fffffffe370. What is wrong here?
I've tried with difference address and format but get the same answer.
****Update
Here is some additional clarification:
    for the test1 with: r $(python3 -c 'print("\x41"*152+"\x42"*6 )')


Vulnearble call @ 0x0000000000400667 <+126>:    callq  0x400460 strcpy@plt

Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400667 <+126>:  callq  0x400460 strcpy@plt
0x000000000040066c <+131>:  lea    -0x90(%rbp),%rdx
0x0000000000400673 <+138>:  lea    -0x90(%rbp),%rax
0x000000000040067a <+145>:  mov    %rax,%rsi
0x000000000040067d <+148>:  lea    0x134(%rip),%rdi        # 0x4007b8
0x0000000000400684 <+155>:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400689 <+160>:  callq  0x400480 printf@plt
0x000000000040068e <+165>:  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400693 <+170>:  leaveq
0x0000000000400694 <+171>:  retq

The break is @ 0x0000000000400694 <+171>:   retq i follow with 'next'

(gdb) next
(gdb) x/256xb $rsp-192
0x7fffffffe370: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe378: 0x8e    0x06    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe380: 0x08    0xe5    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe388: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe390: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe398: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3a0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3a8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3b0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3b8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3c0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3c8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3d0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3d8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3e0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3e8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3f0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3f8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe400: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe408: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe410: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe418: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe420: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe428: 0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe430: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe438: 0x08    0xe5    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe440: 0x00    0x80    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe448: 0xe9    0x05    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe450: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe458: 0x8e    0x14    0xd9    0x63    0x32    0x13    0xbd    0x9e
0x7fffffffe460: 0x90    0x04    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe468: 0x00    0xe5    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00


(gdb) i r
rax            0x0  0
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x0  0
rdx            0x0  0
rsi            0x602260 6300256
rdi            0x1  1
rbp            0x4141414141414141   0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffffffe430   0x7fffffffe430
r8             0x0  0
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x0  0
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x400490 4195472
r13            0x7fffffffe500   140737488348416
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x424242424242   0x424242424242
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0


for the test2 with: r $(python3 -c 'print("\x41"*152+"\x70\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f")')

The break is still @ 0x0000000000400694 <+171>: retq i follow with 'next'

(gdb) next
(gdb) x/256xb $rsp-192

0x7fffffffe370: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe378: 0x8e    0x06    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe380: 0x08    0xe5    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe388: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe390: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe398: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3a0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3a8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3b0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3b8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3c0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3c8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3d0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3d8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3e0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3e8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3f0: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe3f8: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe400: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe408: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe410: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe418: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe420: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7fffffffe428: 0x70    0xc3    0xa3    0xc3    0xbf    0xc3    0xbf    0xc3
0x7fffffffe430: 0xbf    0x7f    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe438: 0x08    0xe5    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe440: 0x00    0x80    0x00    0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe448: 0xe9    0x05    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe450: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe458: 0xb0    0x0b    0xe6    0x1e    0x6c    0x33    0x69    0x0a
0x7fffffffe460: 0x90    0x04    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00

(gdb) i r
rax            0x0      0
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x602260 6300256
rdi            0x1      1
rbp            0x4141414141414141       0x4141414141414141
rsp            0x7fffffffe428   0x7fffffffe428
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x400490 4195472
r13            0x7fffffffe500   140737488348416
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x400694 0x400694 <main+171>
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0


You forgot the 152 bytes of padding?

my bad, to may test version...I corrected with padding but still get wrong rip. The offset is 152

Also it's unclear at what point you are dumping the registers and where that 7fffffffe370 points to.

If you don't set any breakpoints, overwriting with a valid return address should let execution go somewhere instead of page-faulting on code fetch.  (If your stack is executable).  Are you sure the last 2 bytes of the buffer after your string are both zero?
0x7fffffffe370 is a canonical address, but if the high 2 bytes aren't both zero, it won't be so the ret itself would #GP fault before changing RIP.  Single-step with debugger the you're already using and see what's happening.

Try stepi (or nexti if you want to step over calls) to step by a single asm instruction, instead of stepping by a C source line with next.  It could be that a when ret doesn't fault, more than one instruction executes before the debugger gets control again, if you don't actually single-step asm instructions.

Got the same stack result with nexti, ret fault as expected : *Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400694 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe508) at /home/bof.c:49. I do not understand why at 0x7fffffffe428in my stack i don't have0x70 0xe3 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x7f 0x00 0x00`

Looks like a unicode problem. Your string got encoded as utf8.

Tried to encode utf-16, but it seems to not be th problem

It is the problem. 0xe3 in utf8 is 0xc3 0xa3 and 0xff is 0xc3 0xbf which is exactly what you see in the memory dump. utf-16 wouldn't help either. You need to get the bytes into memory unchanged.

Finally, thanks to @Jester, encoding was the problem.
(gdb) r $(python3 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\x41"*152 + b"\x70\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f")')

Solved the isssue.
Same procedure as above gets
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe370 in ?? ()

